# A character of a representation is the largest on the unity

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\rho:G\rightarrow \textrm{GL}(V)$ be a representation of $G$.
Denote the character by $\chi_\rho$.

Is it correct to say that $\chi_\rho (e)\geq \chi_\rho (g)$ for all $g\in G$, where $e$ is the unity?
If so, how can we show it?

Comment: Please carefully read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  You'll find many suggestions for improving your questions.  (Note, you need not do *everything* suggested, but address the key points.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $\rho$ is a representation on a $\Bbb{R}$ vector space for "largest" to make sense.

Letting $n=|G|$,  $g^n=1$ so that each eigenvalue of $\rho(g)$ is a $n$-th root of unity. ie. $\det(X-\rho(g))=\prod_{j=1}^{\dim V} (X-a_j(g))$ and $Tr(\rho(g))=\sum_{j=1}^{\dim V} a_j(g)$ where each $|a_j(g)|=1$.

$Tr(\rho(g))$ is maximum when all the $a_j(g)=1$, in particular for $g=1$.

Comment: Thank you. Did you down-rate my question?

Comment: Given my answer you can probably guess that I didn't